# How can i read this type of json objects in a my sql table

Tags: mysql, sql, json, select, mysql-5.7

[image]

I have this type of json data in a mysql table. how can i read them

```json
[
    {
        "price": "1000",
        "itemcode": "1",
        "itemname": "Break Pads",
        "quantity": "1"
    },
    {
        "price": "800",
        "itemcode": "3",
        "itemname": "Break Oil",
        "quantity": "1"
    }
]
```

Comment: how exactly want to read, e.g. column by column ? and what's the version of your DBMS?

Comment: mysql server 5.7 is the version . i want to read that json coloumn .i dont have any idea how to do that. i want to fetch the data one by one using its key.

Comment: You mean you want each array element to be returned as a row of a result set? You'd have to use the [JSON_TABLE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) function to do that, but it's not implemented in MySQL 5.7. You'll have to upgrade to MySQL 8.0.

Comment: I'm curious why you stored your data in a JSON array if you want to read it as rows? Why not store the data in a normal way, one row at a time, with separate columns for `price`, `itemcode`, `itemname`, `quantity`? If you stored the data in rows and columns, it would be a lot easier to query it.

Comment: this is a database in one of  my java project .think like this, a customer buys more than one item from the shop so i have to insert more items which were bought by the customer in a one cell in my sql column. thats why i used this json data type. now i want to fetch those values from my table. i want to read itemname : value , itemcode : value like that.

Comment: Your reasoning for using the json array has led to a poorly designed database that is difficult to work with. You should consider a redesign.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 5.7, where `JSON_TABLE()` is not available, a typical solution uses a table of numbers.

```
select
    d.*,
    json_unquote(json_extract(
        d.items,
        concat('$[', n.i, '].price')
    )) price,
    json_unquote(json_extract(
        d.items,
        concat('$[', n.i, '].itemcode')
    )) itemcode,
    json_unquote(json_extract(
        d.items,
        concat('$[', n.i, '].itemname')
    )) itemname,
    json_unquote(json_extract(
        d.items,
        concat('$[', n.i, '].quantity')
    )) quantity
from deals d
inner join (
    select 0 i 
    union all select 1
    union all select 2
    union all select 3
) n
    on n.i < json_length(d.items)
```

This would handle up to 4 objects per array. If you need more, you can extend the subquery with more `union all`s.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround emulating `JSON_TABLE()`, which exists in version 8.0, might be given for DB 5.7 as

```
SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(jsdata, CONCAT('$[',@rn+1,'].price'))) AS price,
       JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(jsdata, CONCAT('$[',@rn+1,'].itemcode'))) AS itemcode,
       JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(jsdata, CONCAT('$[',@rn+1,'].itemname'))) AS itemname,
       JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(jsdata, CONCAT('$[',@rn+1,'].quantity'))) AS quantity,
       @rn :=  @rn + 1 as rn
  FROM tab
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := -1
               FROM information_schema.tables) AS iter 
 WHERE @rn < JSON_LENGTH(JSON_EXTRACT(jsdata, '$[*]')) - 1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b0ba9b617083a70c0ad3c8430f5c5f85)</kbd>